Exclude specific folders to not generate their paths using flutter_gen
I am using flutter_gen to generate assets i.e. pngs and svgs. I have 3 folders in my assets folder defined like this in pubspec.yaml.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/svgs/
    - assets/pngs/
    - assets/flags/

But the flags svgs are also being generated which I don't need.
What I actually want:
assets/svgs/... -> should be generated
assets/flags/... -> should not be generated

I tried to define it with exclude parameter.
flutter_gen:
  output: lib/gen/ # Optional (default: lib/gen/)
  line_length: 80 # Optional (default: 80)

  integrations:
    flutter_svg: true

  exclude:
    - assets/flags/

Is there any way to solve this?

I had the same problem.
I forgot to add assets: before the exclude: line.
Also, I had to add /* after each folder name. Seems like it takes file names only, not whole folders.

Update the pubspec.yaml. Use ** for any folder and * for any file.

flutter_gen:
  assets: # add this
    exclude:
      # if you need to exclude any file inside any folder that is inside the flags folder
      - assets/flags/**/*
              
      # if you need to exclude any file inside the flags folder only
      - assets/flags/*


Run fluttergen -c [path-to-pubspec.yaml]

An example of it is on flutter_gen's repo right here.
